# Can I make sudo share cached credentials between terminals?

Tags: shell, sudo

On my Ubuntu, sudo caches credentials. But if I open another terminal window and sudo in that one, the cached credentials are not shared and I have to re-enter my password.

Can I have sudo instances in multiple terminals share cached credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the `tty_tickets` option in sudoers:

```
Defaults !tty_tickets
```

Comment: Thanks, although that's rather broad in its effect. Too broad, really. Is there a way to say "here's a token which grants you, you, and you root access all at once?"

Comment: Too broad? It's exactly what you asked for. And no, sudo doesn't use magic tokens like that, nor does it even cache credentials – all it really does is cache the fact (in /var/db/sudo) that user X on tty Y has recently authenticated. You can limit the option to specific users via `Defaults:spraff` or `Defaults:%wheel` for example, but there's really not much more.